# Custom MVC route appends angular http request url to current url in IE

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm running into a bit of a snag with some custom routing I did. We have these custom routes that handle product perma-links, and I have Angular in the background doing requests to the server for routes that aren't perma-links. This works fine and it will load other pages in every other browser except IE.

What happens in IE is it takes the relative url from the http request and it just appends it, for example:

This is the permalink url, which loads fine:

```
http://localhost:16124/products/7-1-2-contemporary-glass-full-border-award/
```

This is the request in Angular when I click the link to customize this product:

```
 var navigateUrl = "Product/Customize/" + this.productId;
        if (product.isCustomizable != true) {
            navigateUrl = "Cart";    
        }
        this.$window.location.href = navigateUrl;
```

And the url it tries to call is this:

```
http://localhost:16124/products/7-1-2-contemporary-glass-full-border-award/Product/Customize/8036
```

I had a similar problem on other browsers where if I was using Html.ActionLink it would construct the url's for anything inside of the permalink pages it would append the url as a query string, and to fix that I just switched them to plain html links where I wrote out the full relative url myself, but I don't think that is the problem here; does anyone know what could be happening? Again I am only having this issue in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out what the issue was, if you use location.href, in this case IE isn't smart enough to redo the url after the hostname, so it ends up just appending what you had to the end of the url, so changing it to location.pathname will fix the bug because it tells IE to explicitly redo the url after the hostname.